# OpenCV Documentation for Android

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision

I am a newbie to the area of computer vision, with no prior experience. I am trying to develop a face recognition app for Android devices using OpenCV. I have installed OpenCV, but I have no idea how to use it. It seems like there is no Android specific documentation for OpenCV. How can I learn how to use OpenCV in my Android app?

Comment: How about http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html ?

Comment: You can also try http://code.google.com/p/javacv/ which is a Java wrapper for opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best resource I have found is just [OpenCV's Android Tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html). This goes through the opencv android sample code within the samples directory of the source that you extracted to install opencv. (ie.  OPENCV_PATH/samples/android). There are other samples there including one for face detection.

There are also [android docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/platforms/android/service/doc/index.html) on the opencv site.

There is also an opencv [face recognition tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html) which may be useful to get you started even though it is not android specific.

Comment: The core api reference documentation is here as well.  http://docs.opencv.org/java/

Comment: Thanks for noticing. The links should be fixed now.